# Postgresql has permission to file but says it does not

Tags: postgresql, permissions, file-permissions, fedora

I'm getting very strange behavior form PostgreSQL 9.4.4 on Fedora 22:

I'm trying to run this query from `psql`:

```
su - postgres
psql dbName
COPY sometable FROM '/the/file/location.csv' WITH DELIMITER AS ',' CSV;
```

and it is giving me this error:

```
could not open file "/the/file/location.csv" for reading: Permission denied
```

However, if I do this:

```
su - postgres
nano /the/file/location.csv
```

It opens the file as intended because the entire path has read/execute permission for all users.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

**EDIT**: I've now even gone as far as trying to move the files to `/tmp/file.csv`, changing the ownership of the files to `postgres` and shutting off SELinux. Still the same error.

**EDIT 2**: I forgot to mention that this is a Master-Slave setup where I'm SSHing into the Master from the Slave server. The setup is working fine otherwise.

**EDIT 3**: I take back what I originally said. Shutting off SELinux has fixed the problem. I now need to figure out a way to use it in order to fix this properly.

Comment: What user is the Postgres *server* running as?  Admittedly, one might expect it to be "postgres", but the behavior suggests otherwise.

Comment: Do you mean the `/usr/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/pgsql/data` process in `ps aux`? It's running as `postgres`.

Comment: Is your database running on the same machine as your psql frontend?

Comment: Yes, but I'm testing this via SSH.

Comment: The other end of the ssh-connection (where you start psql) *could* have a PGHOST (or PGPORT) environment variable set.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not an advanced user of PostgreSQL, What effect would this have? Also, this reminded me that I didn't mention that this is a Master-Slave setup where I'm SSHing into the Master from the Slave server.

Comment: Ps: If you mean I may be accidentally entering into the local server's `psql`, running `SHOW ALL;` shows the setup of the Master server, not the Slave's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a `SELinux` issue. The file needed the `postgresql_db_t` label.

This can be done by running this command for a single file:

```
chcon --reference /var/lib/pgsql/data/ /the/file/location.csv
```

or this command for an entire directory

```
chcon -R --reference /var/lib/pgsql/data/ /the/directory/
```

These commands tell SELinux to copy the PosgresSQL label/right from PostgreSQL's default directory to the file/directory that PosgreSQL is being denied access.

This can be checked with `ls -lZ`, and it should look something like this afterwards:

```
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 postgres postgres system_u:object_r:postgresql_db_t:s0 0 Jul 26 00:00 fileName.csv
```